# Thread Continues to Execute After Closing the Application

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I have an android application that uses Threads. Application waits for some time, then executes a function.

Things go pretty well if user waits for some time. After the predefined time t ends, the function gets executed.

However, if the user clicks on back button of the device and return to main screen, after the time t ends, the application appears again.

How can I understand if the user pressed back, or closed my application? How can I stop the thread and release everything if I get the leaving message -let's say USER_EXITED?

Answer (score 0):

in your activity when the activity is going to end you can check if it is finishing like this and take care of things to do with your threads

```
@Override 
public void onPause() {        

        if(isFinishing()){
//put the correct checks or shutdowns

{            


    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create a Service.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html